How can I get a WordPress shortcode evaluated within a template if I cannot edit the template php files?
I have created a WordPress shortcode (using the Code Snippets plugin) that works fine.
I need it to work within a template so, on my local system, I have edited post-content.php and inserted
$content .= do_shortcode('...');
and that works fine.
I now want to move this to a public server where I do not have permission to edit WordPress template php files.
How can I get the shortcode evaluated within a template if I cannot edit the php files (but I can add code for filters etc)?
I have managed to find solutions to all the other complex things I need to do by using php functions and filters. I have searched for solutions to this issue but the only ones I can find are about editing template files.

This could do with a bit more detail - like, what part of the template is this in, does it execute any filters on that $content variable close to the location where you need to put this, etc. Maybe the the_content filter could help already, using it to call do_shortcode and append the result ...?

Thanks.  I will explore doing the change I need via the_content filter, rather than changing the template.

I have not answered the question directly, but my issue is sorted now - by doing what I want to do in a different way. Thanks for the steer.
